# Logback does not write logs to a file

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, logback

I have a Java-standalone REST application, which is inside Tomсat. I need to output logs to a file, I use logback. But logs are not written to the file. They are displayed in the console, although I removed the console appender. If you try on a Windows machine, everything goes fine. Trying on RedHat (does not have a GUI), the logs are not output to the file (although they should) and are output to the console (although they should not be displayed). The application works exactly, responds to queries.

**Logback.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="/var/tmp" />
    <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/mytest.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/mytest-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>2KB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>4</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>10KB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

In Eclipse I do export to Runnable jar file, I throw it on a Linux machine. I run as follows:

```
java -jar test.jar &
```

Comment: Have you tried `mvn clean install` after deleting the console appender? Keep in mind that your program should have permissions to write on `${DEV_HOME}`. _In eclipse I do export to Runnable jar file_ How do you do that? (right click -> export -> runnable jar file?)

Comment: @ManuRivas, mvn clean install didn't try. Well I from under the user can create in directory /var/tmp the empty file, I launch application from under the user too. I think I can write to the log. In eclipse I do everything the way you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had the same scenario with jboss EAP 7.0 every thing was working fine on the window machine but as soon as i was taking it to linux machine . it wont write a single word. 
[application.properties for logging]

second i had move log4j.properties in Jboss bin folder. application.properties file and the same file in springboot application resources.

[image]

After that restart the server and you will found the loggs written on the specified folder

Comment: can you please include your code as text? look it up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-blockquotes)